# Are there any tools for finding words that commonly modify other words?

Tags: word-choice

For example, the most common modifiers for the word "car" might be "used", "stolen" and "rented". I think this could be a very useful tool when you are writing and you are looking for a particular word, but you can't remember what it is. A web tool would be ideal, but that's not necessary

Comment: Use google on the word and look at the examples it gives you, the words around 'car'.

Comment: @Casebash: Before you go too far along that road, you might like to note that ***his, her, big, small** car*, for example, are all far more common collocations than *used* or *stolen*. And even ***black, red** car* are more common that *rented*. For reasons that escape me, ***grey*** and ***silver** car* occur relatively infrequently in Google Books, even though they're probably the most common ones actually on the road (in Britain, at least).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for resources.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's probably exactly because the color is so common that they aren't used often in books.  They aren't exciting - red (fast! passion! etc) and black (cool, dark, scary, secret, etc) are probably most used (at a guess, blue and/or yellow are probably close behind).

Comment: @Doc: Except that I specifically said *probably* because it's a toss-up between *black* and *grey/silver* which is actually the most common! I see what you mean though - writers use modifiers that will tend to evoke a reaction (if the car is fictional anyway, the writer may as well make it a colour that *means* something to the reader, otherwise why mention the colour at all?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [English Collocation Dictionary Online](http://www.ozdic.com/) and other dictionaries of collocations give common collocates; many of these will be of the form modifier + headword.

Answer (score 1):

You can find related words and phrases to particular word on [Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/car). There are not the most common modifiers, but I think it could help you while writing as there are the phrases which are used with it.